# Mirror display in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, display

I have two old VGA cards.

One of them is a MX440 NVidia card.

The other is a PCI Rage XL.

Is there a free tool that would allow me to mirror these cards?

I can't seem to find it anywhere on the web.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the flag that says which is the primary desktop.

For your demo, make the second monitor *primary* instead of *extended*.
Change it back when you're done.

Or maybe get a VGA splitter – you can then hook two monitors to same port.

Comment: I don't get it. 

1. Which flag is that?

2. If I change this flag, wouldn't this just change the primary monitor? Or can I have two primary monitors?

A splitter wouldn't help me much. Sometimes I'd like to use the monitors independently. Other times, I want them mirrored. A splitter would solve the mirroring problem. But it wouldn't allow me to change this programatically.